# Is it possible to connect to MS SQL server via HAProxy?

Tags: sql-server, haproxy

I need to be able to connect to MS SQL server hosted on Amazon (RDS, single AZ) via HAProxy. I tried the following configuration (bottom) but MS SQL returned me (although I used valid login and password):

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
>   error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10054)

```
listen RDS_MSSQL *:1433
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option log-health-checks
    server legacy xxxx.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1433 check port 1433 inter 1000
```

Comment: Have you checked that haproxy thinks that the SQL server is up? That's the error I would expect if haproxy can't connect to the SQL server.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. Instead of `listen` I use a `frontend` block and a `backend` block:

```
frontend tcp-in-mssql
  bind :8800
  mode tcp
  use_backend mssql

backend mssql
  mode tcp
  server mssqlserver 10.10.10.10:1433 check
```

Comment: `listen` seems to be encouraged by the `haproxy` docs so why is it better to split this into `backend` and `fronend`?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209917/difference-between-frontend-backend-and-listen-in-haproxy

Comment: I prefer to specify a different incoming port on the frontend and then route it through to the mssql port on the backend. I'll update my answer to show that.

Answer (score -3):

Looks like it's impossible by default due to three-way handshake required by MS SQL
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/287932

Other database server like PostgreSQL don't require this special handling and work well via HAProxy

Comment: That three-way handshake they talk about is the standard TCP handshake. Nothing in that article implies that a load balancer won't work.